# How to login and redirect through HttpClient in java

Tags: java, redirect, authentication, httpclient

Though there are multiple such questions, infact the various answers confused me.....I am using HttpClient 4.X.X

there is a URL http://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi  which is for logging in rediffmail....I am passing 
login=my_username&passwd=my_password&submit=GO&FormName=existing with the the above URL.....when it is done on browser as 
http://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi?login=my_username&passwd=my_password&submit=GO&FormName=existing

It correctly logs me in and takes me to my mail page

but when I am doing through HttpClient

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi?login=my_username&passwd=my_password&submit=GO&FormName=existing");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    //  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        String responseVal = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler); System.out.println(responseVal);
```

This gives me output in a HTML with

> javascript in the header as - 
>   window.location.replace("http://f1mail.rediff.com/iris/postlogin.php?login=my_username&
>    session_id=1L4PK1KHKGIpbBG5OlVVdOzip1m7wyU&farm=1&showinbox=&mobilelogin=&url=");
>
> body as -
>   If you are seeing this page, your browser settings prevent you from automatically redirecting to a new URL.
>
> Please < a href="http://f1mail.rediff.com/iris/postlogin.php?login=my_username&
>   session_id=1L4PK1KHKGIpbBG5OlVVdOzip1m7wyU&farm=1&showinbox=&mobilelogin=&url=">click here to continue.

whereas I want it to get redirected fully as it gets into the browser........and I wanted to use that final URL further.

Any guidance or moreover clarification would be helpful.....

Thanks
Sam
te

Comment: You will have to parse the HTML file, get the URL and navigate to it.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if you reproduce the same HTTP request in Java the result should be the same. So there must be some difference between the Java call and the real one.

My advice is to use some tools to get every parameter that's being passed in the HTTP request. I would recommend using Chrome's dev tools (CMD+ALT+i on Mac) or Firefox's Firebug extension to inspect the HTTP request. I took a look at it myself:

**[rant]**
OK, I had a beautiful screenshot of the Network inspector showing the request, but I still have to earn 10 points to post images to stackoverflow. Sorry man!
**[end-of-rant]**

The first thing I noticed is that you need to make a POST request, not a GET. Other detail could be slipping, making your Java HTTP request fail.

I would recommend giving a try to some REST client so you can build the request and try it before getting to the Java code. There are some standalone clients, as well as some Chrome and FireFox extensions.
Once it works, you'll just need to pour it into your Java code, et voilà.

Cheers!